# How to exclude specific folders while compiling .vue templates with Laravel Mix?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, vuejs3, laravel-mix

I want to prevent some .vue files in specific directories to be compiled by `mix.vue()`

For instance; I have two folders for vue components in resources directory named "base-components" and "other-components". I don't want .vue components in "other-components" to be compiled when I run `npm run prod` (or watch etc.)

How can I do this?

Comment: I am sorry but I did not understand anything, why would you not want `other-components` folder to be read by `mix.vue()`, hence compiling those components? Why do you have `.vue` components there then? It makes no sense at all... Explain more please, so we can help you.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I am trying to compile two different javascript files. The folder names are examples. Just think frontend and backend files will be separated. So I need to compile some vue files for frontend and some other for backend. I don't want to serve them together.

Comment: I am sorry but I still do not understand, are you serving `Vue` doing `SSR` (Server Side Rendering) and that is why you have some backend and frontend `Vue` files?

Comment: Just think about webpack configuration. You can exclude directories to prevent the files inside being compiled. But Laravel Mix prepares own webpack configuration. So I need to add directories to exclude from compilation.

Comment: Yes, I know you can exclude files using webpack, I just do not know much about it, what I am curious about is why you want to exclude `.vue` files from compiling, why would you not want to compile and serve some `.vue` files if those are only for frontend? You did not answer my SSR question.

Comment: I want to create separate javascript files for website and admin panel. That's why I am trying to exclude them.

Comment: Oh, so you don't want to compile on the same final file a normal "user" vue component and an "admin" vue component, so the admin HTML only knows the URL to that asset, right? To be honest, I am not sure if that is "easy" to do, because compiling a vue asset from a specific folder into another specific public folder, I think that is not worth it (not as easy as it seems), but I could be totally wrong, I am sorry I cannot help. You can read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#vendor-extraction) and the next part of the documentation but I am not sure if it will help.

Comment: It may not be easy but I am near to succeed. I am using two different mix configurations, two different webpack configurations and even two different tailwind configurations. Everything is okay except excluding some folders to be compiled. I need to exclude admin components in normal user configuration and exlude normal user components in admin configuration.